# How to implement virtual function override for class vars

Tags: c++, class, variables, virtual

In the sample below I would like to create local overrides within each TradingStrategy(1-N).cpp file. Can someone tell me the most straight-forward/standard way to implement this in c++?

Thanks,
Mike

```
// TradingSide.h file
class BuySide: public CTradingSide{
public:
BuySide(CBMTTradingStrategy *p_Strategy, bool  p_buySellSide, u32 p_spotInstIndex, u32 p_futInstIndex );
~BuySide();
virtual void    onQuoteBuyExit( u32 p_instIndex );
virtual void    onQuoteBuyEntry( u32 p_instIndex );
virtual void    onFIXBuyEntry( u32 p_orderIndex, bmt_eng_events_t p_orderEvent );
virtual void    onFIXBuyExit( u32 p_orderIndex, bmt_eng_events_t p_orderEvent );
virtual inline bool isBuyEntryCriteriaSatisfied( bmt_price_t &p_spotCash, u32 &p_buySpotQty  );
};

class SellSide: public CTradingSide{
public:
SellSide(CBMTTradingStrategy *p_Strategy, bool  p_buySellSide, u32 p_spotInstIndex, u32 p_futInstIndex );
~SellSide();
virtual void    onQuoteSellExit( u32 p_instIndex );
virtual void    onQuoteSellEntry( u32 p_instIndex );
virtual void    onFIXSellEntry( u32 p_orderIndex, bmt_eng_events_t p_orderEvent );
virtual void    onFIXSellExit( u32 p_orderIndex, bmt_eng_events_t p_orderEvent );
virtual inline bool isSellEntryCriteriaSatisfied( bmt_price_t &p_spotCash, u32 &p_sellSpotQty  );
};

// TradingStrategy1.h file
class Trading1Class: public ParentClass{
...
SellSide    *mySellSide;
BuySide *myBuySide;
}
// TradingStrategy1.cpp file
Trading1Class::BuySide::onQuoteBuyExit( u32 p_instIndex )
{
...
}

// TradingStrategy2.h file
class Trading2Class: public ParentClass{
...
SellSide    *mySellSide;
BuySide *myBuySide;
}
// TradingStrategy2.cpp file
Trading1Class::BuySide::onQuoteBuyExit( u32 p_instIndex )
{
...
}
```

Comment: Implement what exactly? How to write the function that doest the trading transaction?

Comment: You could create nested class' in each of the Trading(1-n) classes, and have those extend BuySide/SellSide instead. I.e: Trading1Class : public ParentClass { ... class MySellSide : public SellSide { onQuoteBuyExit(u32 p_instIndex) { ... }}; };

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'local override', and you cannot write different bodies for the same method, but after some redesigning it should should become possible to achieve your goal (I think virtual methods would be the best fit).

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to do this:

1. Inherit from your `BuySide` class N times and override methods here. Use different `BuySide` descendants for different `TradingStragegy`.
2. Move the `BuySide` into the parent class, make the `onQuoteByExit` to call a virtual method of `ParentClass` and override this virtual method in descendants.
3. Add a method-pointer field into `BuyClass` and assign it in constructors of `TradingNClass`. Use this field to call a method pointed by it from `onQuoteByExit` method of `BuyClass`.

I personally would prefer the second way. I guess all these `on*` methods should be implemented (overridden) by the strategies, then it's simpler to have them in the base class.

Comment: Guys, thanks for the feedback. I've made the suggested changes and opted for option 2 above.

Comment: Guys, thanks for the feedback. I've made the suggested changes and opted for option 2 above.